# glDrawArrays: Same attribute for all triangles

Tags: opengl, shader

I understand it is possible to set per-instance attributes when drawing with `glDrawArraysInstanced` and friends, so I was wondering if it's also possible to set an attribute once (i.e. per instance) for all vertices generated by `glDrawArrays` instead of setting them individually for each vertex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly. For example if your attribute is a `vec4`, and the attribute location is `attrLoc`, you can use one of the following to set an attribute value that applies to the whole draw call:

```
glVertexAttrib4f(attrLoc, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
glDrawArrays(...);

GLfloat attrVal[4] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
glVertexAttrib4fv(attrLoc, attrVal);
glDrawArrays(...);
```

There are equivalent calls for vectors with 1, 2, and 3 members.

Comment: Huh! Didn't know about `glVertexAttrib`. Thanks.